# Should I use filtered graph or subgraph or something else?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am using BGL recently, and I have a graph G now. I need a data structure that can rule out one vertex at a time, without breaking the original graph. What should I do? 
At first I found the filtered graph, but I need to label all vertices, and create a new filtered graph after I rule out a vertex. If I have N vertices in the graph, I need to filter N times. 
I also thought of a subgraph, but it doesn't support removing vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filtered graph.

You can have a dynamic filter predicate that incrementally filters out more vertices. No need to create more filtered graphs at all.

See an example:

- [Using two objects as hash key for an unordered_map or alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279268/using-two-objects-as-hash-key-for-an-unordered-map-or-alternatives/32281365?s=1|0.0000#32281365)
- [boost graph copy and removing vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522732/boost-graph-copy-and-removing-vertex/31527110?s=2|0.0000#31527110)
- [Remove 100,000+ nodes from a Boost graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376370/remove-100-000-nodes-from-a-boost-graph/28376521?s=3|0.0000#28376521)

Comment: Why would it be a problem? Also, why would you need "`is_not_a_subets<>`"? I think you're discussing a part of your problem that you never told us about.

Comment: Plus, I must say, the Boost documentation is far from complete. It fails me too many times that I must ask on this site now, and more in the future.

Comment: Oh. You think I have magic information? I get it from the same documentation. I started livestreaming my answers (https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/) **just** so that people (like you!) can see how I go about finding the information and how many times I fail and have to fix compiler errors. How I read them and think about it (mostly out loud). Perhaps that helps you get more patience and embrace C++ for what it is.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. If that costs you that many times to find what it should be, it means exactly that the documentation is incomplete.Plus, I want to know what the predicate is like when creating the filtered graph, in my problem.

Comment: To me, it means your patience is incomplete. Or you have a complex that makes you feel bad for asking. Whichever it is, it's not very constructive. It is how it is. Why did I spend the time learning this? Because I know I can be more productive when I need it. Also, I learn how to learn. I've learnt more about learning on [SO] than about any boost library.

Comment: @AurusHuang Oh, I missed the "question" in your comment. I can't answer it because you don't show the "my problem" part. Perhaps you should post a new question. In the mean time I think [this linked example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31527110/85371) should be close to your question (look for `removed_set`)

Comment: I'm really think of that. I'm sorry that I didn't express that. All of your examples are given really close to my problem, the only problem is that I'm still wondering what the codes mean.

Comment: You can ask. All I know now is you're wondering. About ... something. I could do a livecoding session. I have ~30 minutes left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92231/discussion-between-aurus-huang-and-sehe).

Comment: It works this morning. Plus, the documentation doesn't cover so many valuable stuff written in codes, and that's why I mean it incomplete.